# Can you create rich websites (more than just text) using Google Sites?

Tags: html, google-sites

After trying out Google Sites to create a website, I feel it is very limited to mainly text features. I have tried to find a way to implement elements directly using HTML, but to no avail. Buttons are completely blocked, which is a great disadvantage.

I have tried JQuery, but all script is blocked.

Is there anyway to implement elements like `<img>` using Google Sites HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create rich websites using Google sites including images for sure.

We have recently finished working on a website for IMA and they created a list pointing to other local chapters. Check this link:

http://imamiddleeast.org/networking-local-chapters/local-chapters

While the website we built is Drupal based, it looks like most of the local chapters are using Google Sites. For example:

http://abudhabi.imanet.org/

http://dubai.imanet.org/

Check out the examples and see how rich they are.

Comment: The sites you show are examples proving rich-text elements are possible. You do not explain how though.

Comment: I don't have access to the sites to give details. However, in general, scripts and fiddling with HTML will be blocked in the WYSIWYG editor and you'll have to use the WYSIWYG buttons to insert images (make sure you check all the buttons there after you set your cursor inside the WYSIWYG) and also in other tabs of the editing interface. Good luck.